# How to configure clang-format to use my prefered indentation?

Tags: plugin-clang-format

I'm consulting the [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) to configure my [clang-format](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-clang-format).

Here's my current setup of `g:clang_format#style_options`:

```
let g:clang_format#style_options = {
                \ "AccessModifierOffset": 4,
                \ "AlignAfterOpenBracket": "Align",
                \ "AlignConsecutiveAssignments": "true",
                \ "AlignConsecutiveDeclarations": "true",
                \ "AlignConsecutiveMacros": "true",
                \ "AlignEscapedNewlines": "Left",
                \ "AlignTrailingComments": "true",
                \ "AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine": "true",
                \ "AllowAllConstructorInitializersOnNextLine": "true",
                \ "AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine": "true",
                \ "AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine": "Never",
                \ "AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine": "false",
                \ "AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine": "None",
                \ "AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine": "Never",
                \ "AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine": "Inline",
                \ "AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine": "false",
                \ "AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType": "None",
                \ "AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings": "false",
                \ "AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations": "Yes",
                \ "BinPackArguments": "false",
                \ "BinPackParameters": "false",
                \ "BreakBeforeBinaryOperators": "None",
                \ "BreakBeforeBraces": "Allman",
                \ "BreakConstructorInitializers": "AfterColon",
                \ "BreakInheritanceList": "AfterColon",
                \ "BreakStringLiterals": "true",
                \ "ColumnLimit": 0,
                \ "CompactNamespaces": "false",
                \ "ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine": "false",
                \ "ConstructorInitializerIndentWidth": 4,
                \ "ContinuationIndentWidth": 4,
                \ "Cpp11BracedListStyle": "false",
                \ "DerivePointerAlignment": "true",
                \ "FixNamespaceComments": "false",
                \ "IncludeBlocks": "Regroup",
                \ "IndentGotoLabels": "true",
                \ "IndentPPDirectives": "BeforeHash",
                \ "IndentWidth": 4,
                \ "IndentWrappedFunctionNames": "false",
                \ "KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks": "false",
                \ "Language": "Cpp",
                \ "NamespaceIndentation": "All",
                \ "PointerAlignment": "Left",
                \ "ReflowComments": "true",
                \ "SortIncludes": "true",
                \ "SortUsingDeclarations": "true",
                \ "SpaceAfterCStyleCast": "true",
                \ "SpaceAfterLogicalNot": "false",
                \ "SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword": "true",
                \ "SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators": "true",
                \ "SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList": "true",
                \ "SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon": "false",
                \ "SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon": "false",
                \ "SpaceBeforeParens": "Never",
                \ "SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon": "false",
                \ "SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets": "false",
                \ "SpaceInEmptyBlock": "false",
                \ "SpaceInEmptyParentheses": "false",
                \ "SpacesBeforeTrailingComments": 2,
                \ "UseCRLF": "false",
                \ "UseTab": "Always"
                \ }
```

I'm currently dissatisfied with the current indentations of this setting.

My preferred indenting:

```
typedef class Node * node;
class Node
{
    private:
        int data;
        bool red;
        node parent;
        node left;
        node right;

    public:
        Node( int data, bool red, node parent, node left, node right )
        {
            this->data = data;
            this->red = red;
            this->parent = parent;
            this->left = left;
            this->right = right;
        }

        bool operator < (const node other)
        {
            return this->data < other->data;
        }

        bool operator > (const node other)
        {
            return this->data > other->data;
        }

        bool operator <= (const node other)
        {
            return this->data <= other->data;
        }

        bool operator >= (const node other)
        {
            return this->data >= other->data;
        }

        bool operator == (const node other)
        {
            return this->data == other->data;
        }

        void flipColor()
        {
            this->red = !this->red;
        }

        int getData()
        {
            return this->data;
        }
};
```

The result of my current setting:

```
typedef class Node* node;
class Node
{
    private:
    int  data;
    bool red;
    node parent;
    node left;
    node right;

    public:
    Node(int data, bool red, node parent, node left, node right)
    {
    this->data   = data;
    this->red    = red;
    this->parent = parent;
    this->left   = left;
    this->right  = right;
    }

    bool operator<(const node other)
    {
    return this->data < other->data;
    }

    bool operator>(const node other)
    {
    return this->data > other->data;
    }

    bool operator<=(const node other)
    {
    return this->data <= other->data;
    }

    bool operator>=(const node other)
    {
    return this->data >= other->data;
    }

    bool operator==(const node other)
    {
    return this->data == other->data;
    }

    void flipColor()
    {
    this->red = !this->red;
    }

    int getData()
    {
    return this->data;
    }
};
```

For me, I prefer indentation after each `private:`/`protected:`/`public:` and after every `{`. I've tried playing around with some of the parameters, especially `"BreakBeforeBraces"`. I've tried all the options for it (from the style options page) but none has given me my preferred indentation. How can I make `clang-format` indent after every scope keyword and `{`s?

Comment: Is part of the problem a tabs vs. spaces issue? Do you have `:set ts=4` and some of the lines have a tab vs. others which have four spaces? Try `:set list` to see the tabs?

Comment: Setting tabs to 3 actually solved the problem. I had set all the tabs in vim to be 4 but just setting `"IndentWidth" = 3` fixed all that.